# MongoDb find query giving weird response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to search data in mongodb with nodejs. This is my query

```
collection.find({ age: { '$gt': 20 } });
```

its working fine in robomongo but giving me this response in my application

```
Readable {
 pool: null,
 server: null,
 disconnectHandler: 
  { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
   length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'versioncontrol.Branch/contacts',
 cmd: 
  { find: 'versioncontrol.Branch/contacts',
    limit: 0,
 skip: 0,
  query: { age: [Object] },
 slaveOk: true,
 readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] } }
```

Now i don't know how to get my data out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor returned from the find method is a Readable stream. You have do read items from it to get the actual result. Look at [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/streams/)

Example:

```
var cursor = collection.find({ age: { '$gt': 20 } });
cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Fetched:', doc);
  }
});
```

Comment: How should I run it in testCase? wont it cause async issues?

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: i did it this way.
var cursor = collection.find({ age: { '$gt': 20 } }).toArray(); 
Because i wanted all the records together

Answer (score 0):

Done it using

```
var cursor = collection.find({ age: { '$gt': 20 } }).toArray();
cursor.then(function (docs) {
 console.log( docs ); 
});
```